# Clarifying a right angle in a bisected triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, angle

Here is a question that I was doing this morning:

[image]

Part of the mark scheme makes use of the following:

[image]

**My question:** How do we know that the bisector of the angle DAB meets the midpoint at a right angle?

Thanks.

Comment: $AD = AB$, $DM = BM$, $AM$ is common, so $\triangle ADM = \triangle ABM$. $\angle AMB = \angle AMD$ and they add up to $180^\circ$.

Comment: $DA=AB=3r$ are radii for the big circle. Therefore $\triangle DAB$ is isosceles.